How to define custom/user defined partition key in AWS DMS
I want to define custom/user defined partition key to the records in AWS DMS before pushing them to AWS Kinesis.
The idea is to keep same partition key for table 1 and table 2 and push them into kinsies, so that they will pushed into same shard and have another partition key for records from table 3 and table 4, so that they will be pushed into the same shard.
I have gone through the official aws documentation and other links as well, but i couldnt find a way to define user-defined partition key in AWS DMS. All I could find is define schemaName-tableName or value of a column as a partition key.
Is there an option in AWS DMS to set user-defined parition key? If yes, how it should be done.
